# i getting an error expecting a semicolon,found 'sc'?

Tags: apex, class

```
public class casess {
    public static void invokebatch(list<cases> css){
        for(case dsv:css){
            shadow case_c sc=new shadow case_c();
            sc.caseid=dsv.Id;
            sc.casenumber=dsv.CaseNumber;
            sc.casestatus=dsv.Status;
        }      
    }  
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE, kindly go through the [tour](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour) section to get a feel of this community and how it works. Then, check out [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article to know what details you need to include for the question to be answered quickly and avoid getting negative reputation.

Comment: shadow case_c sc=new shadow case_c(); what is the api name for 
shadow case_c ? please use proper API Name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're not referencing to your custom object properly. That's why you're getting an error. It should be something like this `shadow_case__c`. Use **API** name of your custom object correctly. Your code should be something like this:

```
 public class casess {
    public static void invokebatch(list<cases> css){
        for(case dsv:css){
            // API name of your custom object
            shadow_case__c sc=new shadow_case__c ();
            sc.caseid=dsv.Id;
            sc.casenumber=dsv.CaseNumber;
            sc.casestatus=dsv.Status;
        }      
    }  
}
```

If you're planning to use `shadow_case__c` further then as per standard practice you should use `List`. This will reduce your **DML** queries. Sample Example:

```
public class casess {
    public static void invokebatch (list<cases> css){
        List<shadow_case__c> showCaseList = new List<shadow_case__c> ();

        for (case dsv : css) {
            // API name of your custom object
            shadow_case__c sc = new shadow_case__c ();
            sc.caseid = dsv.Id;
            sc.casenumber = dsv.CaseNumber;
            sc.casestatus = dsv.Status;
            showCaseList.add (sc);
        }      
        // further processing of showCaseList
    }  
}
```

Comment: thank you rohit. ya i forget to write shadow_case_c.thank you for  your answer